# Bash Can the ternary operator be used to set values to multiple variables?

Tags: bash, conditional-operator

the (pseudo) code for what i want to do:

```
n=100
desired=""
for i in {1..10} ; do
    (( $(numeric_command_output) < n ?
        set n to the output and desired to $i :
        keep n and desired unchanged )) ; done
```

I know how to manipulate one variable based on the condition using ternary operator, but can this be done in bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can the ternary operator be used to set values to multiple variables?

Yes.

> but can this be done in bash?

Yes.

```
(( ( tmp=$(numeric_command_output) ) < n ? (n=tmp, desired=$i) : 0 ))
```

or

```
(( tmp=$(numeric_command_output, tmp < n ? (n=tmp, desired=$i) : 0 ))
```

Comment: kudos! although there are certainly much simpler and more readable ways of doing this, i was just itching to see if this could be done. I didn't know about the list `,` operator for arithmetic evaluation in bash. thanks!... just one thing, is the `: 0` part to signify arithmetic `false`?

Comment: `the list , operator` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator `: 0 part to signify arithmetic false` No, just there have to be something after `:`. `0` might be a bad choice, cause it's false, `set -e` might exit the script, putting something positive would be better.

Comment: "putting something positive would be better". or, in this case `continue`? I mean we are at the last command of the `for` block.

Comment: `continue` is an undefined variable, which would evaluate to `0` inside `((` command.  Unless `conitnue=something` then it would be evaluated. I would put there something like `7`, because it's lucky in my culture, or `1`. `we are at the last command of the for block` The `((` command does not evaluate commands nor does it affect control flow. The `((` command only evaluates arithmetic expressions. https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic